# Lua-openssl - all openssl submodules are nil

Tags: lua, null, openssl

I'm trying to follow the instructions from the readme file here: https://github.com/zhaozg/lua-openssl

This is a basic program I'm running:

```
openssl = require 'openssl'
inspect = require 'inspect'
print(inspect(openssl.cipher))
```

Only 'nil' gets printed to the terminal.

If I try to inspect the "openssl" object, I get the following output:

```
{
  NO_IDEA = true,
  NO_MD2 = true,
  NO_MDC2 = true,
  NO_RC5 = true,
  NO_SCTP = true,
  SHLIB_VERSION_HISTORY = "",
  SHLIB_VERSION_NUMBER = "1.1",
  SSLEAY_BUILT_ON = 2,
  SSLEAY_CFLAGS = 1,
  SSLEAY_DIR = 4,
  SSLEAY_PLATFORM = 3,
  SSLEAY_VERSION = 0,
  SSLEAY_VERSION_NUMBER = 269484159,
  VERSION_NUMBER = 269484159,
  VERSION_TEXT = "OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017",
  version = <function 1>
}
```

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From that documentation, don't you need to `require'openssl'.cipher()`?

Comment: @Corsaka I get this error: "attempt to call a nil value (field 'cipher')". So the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

The version that comes with your system may not have yet the cipher module, or may be another binding for openssl.

Check the modules that your version has in the folder where lua openssl is located, in my system is in `/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/openssl/`, there is also a file outside the folder `/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/openssl.lua` and the shared object in `/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/_openssl.so` but in yours it may vary.

Backup those files to another place just to make sure. Remove them and install the latest version with luarocks.

```
luarocks install openssl
```

Luarocks will probably install the new shared object in `/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/`. If the name of the module installed has the version in the name like `openssl_0_7_7_0-openssl.so` rename it to `openssl.so`.

Comment: Sadly even "luarocks install openssl" doesn't work (missing X509_ALGOR_cmp), that's why I decided to build from source.